# DataReader and large datasets

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ado.net, sqldatareader, datareader

I have a query that returns between 10k and 20k rows.  I'm dumping this data into a `IEnumerable<T>` in what as far as I know is the fastest possible way:

```
using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    var trackIdCol = rdr.GetOrdinal("TrackId");
    var dateTimeCol = rdr.GetOrdinal("ActDateTime");
    var clicksCol = rdr.GetOrdinal("Clicks");
    var ipCol = rdr.GetOrdinal("IPAddress");
    while (rdr.Read()) {
        yield return new SiteClick() {
            TrackId = (int)rdr[trackIdCol],
            DateTime = (DateTime)rdr[dateTimeCol],
            Clicks = (int)rdr[clicksCol],
            IPAddress = rdr[ipCol] as string
        };
    }
}
```

The query takes about 11s to return all the results in SSMS and SSDT, but the code above takes over 2 minutes.  There has to be something I'm doing wrong here.  `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` also takes about 2 minutes to run, if that helps.

It is worth noting that our database is horribly unoptimized.  Just the fact that it takes 11 seconds to get results from that query in SSMS is ridiculous, but I gotta work with what I got. If the query executes quickly in SSMS, but an empty `while(rdr.Read()){}` still takes 2 minutes, it is possible that the DB is still the issue?

Comment: You don't show your select statement. Are you retrieving only these columns, or do you have other data as well. How fast is this query if you run it from a different tool entirely (that actually retrieves all of the data). Of course, is it really necessary to read 10K rows of data to the client app?

Comment: It is for a large report that generates an Excel sheet, so yes, it unfortunately is necessary to load all the records into the client.  The select statement retrieves only these columns amd as my question states, takes only 11 seconds to execute.

Comment: I just tried mostly equivalent code, after populating a table with 20K rows, the initial query, a fraction of a second, reading 20K rows, maybe 1 third of a second. So, either the SiteClick() constructor is slow, or you have a very slow data connection to your DB, or you are not showing the code you are actually running. Since Adapter.Fill() takes 2 minutes, I am pretty sure you database pipe is very slow. That is why I initially asked if you have a different tool -- if nothing else using sqlcmd from a CMD prompt.

Comment: I use a LinqToSQL method when I have this need. It basically gives you a typed streaming SQLDataReader. I do not think this is your problem though. SQLDataAdapter.Fill is fast, so filling it with 20k rows should take a second or less. My best guess is that you simply have a slow query, parameter sniffing, etc. We would need to see your query, indexes, etc, to help if so.

Comment: The query does not take 11 seconds to run. It takes 11 seconds until it delivers the FIRST RESULT. The query will finish near the end of the while loop, when all data has been processed and ONLY the send buffers are remaining. On top, please, do not call 10.000 to 20.000 rows a large data set. There are people here dealing with data sets in the double digit million that they aggregate and process.

Comment: @TomTom, see my changes to the last few sentences.  The query executes completely and returns all results in SSMS and SSDT in 11 seconds.  After looking around on here for "fast in SSMS but not in .NET" I see suggestions for `SET ARITHABORT ON`, which I tried with no improvement.

Comment: Is this taking 2 minutes with nothing else (I.e. empty foreach)? That would be very suspicious - I process large amounds in a lot less time regularly.

Comment: Yes, and empty loop also takes 2 minutes.  If the query runs quickly in SSMS, but an empty loop is slow, is possible that it's still ultimately the database that's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can't dump into IEnumerable, because it is interface that must have implementation behind the scene. In your sample yield used as such implementation. But yield is rather expensive. For every iteration its state is saved, then restored and this is slow for database objects.

Database reader is the fastest iterator itself. So if you can use it directly - this will
be the fastest way. But there is a drawback, because such database cursors might lock
db tables for access from other threads. So use it in single-user environments or
when you can read uncommitted data.

To reduce locking time you can dump data into in-memory IEnumerable implementations.
For example, List. Just set larger capacity to avoid frequent allocations, so it
will be as fast as underlying array. The drawback of such solution is memory usage. But
in you case this will be less than 1M.

```
List<SiteClick> list = new List<SiteClick>(20000);
```

Also you can improve performance and memory usage if define SiteClick as struct, not class.
In this case list will contain objects, not references.

A little bit additional performance you can get if use typified reader methods.

```
TrackId = rdr.GetInt32(trackIdCol),
DateTime = rdr.GetDateTime(dateTimeCol),
Clicks = rdr.GetInt32(clicksCol),
IPAddress = rdr.GetString(ipCol)
```

**UPDATE**: For SQL Server it's a frequent case, when queries are tested in SSMS. But there are some issues, because SMSS has different options compared to database defaults. For example, ARITHABORT. So you can set it manually for connection to test.

```
// Use the same connection as for data reading
var cmdOptions = connection.CreateCommand();
cmdOptions.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmdOptions.CommandText = "SET ARITHABORT ON";
cmdOptions.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

According to MS recommendations - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933126%28SQL.80%29.aspx, its better to ensure that you have these options set:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
```

Comment: This report is run against a production database; unfortunately creating a database specifically for reporting is not an option.  I've implemented both of your suggestions but I see no improvement at all.  Are there no other methods for improvement?

Comment: 1. How do you measure the query time? Do you clear the buffers before test? Do you use stored procs?
2. Does it work faster in release mode?
3. Does the empty reader loop (just "while (rdr.Read()) {} ") works also slow.
4. Take a look at answer's update, it didn't fit in comment))

Comment: 1) I'm timing the query in SSMS by simple noting the execution time in the status bar.  I'm timing it in my code with `DateTime.Now` then a difference.  2) Stored Procs are not feasible for this particular query. 3) Yes, an empty `while` still takes 2 minutes.

Comment: Does the query contains any UDF calls, indexed views? Can you show it? SqlDataReader has to be working much faster than SSMS output. So in case you are launching both SSMS and application with the equal network configuration, the problem usually caused by caching/connection options. Check the "SELECT @@OPTIONS" result from both SSMS and app.